# How to install wireless driver on Debian7 wheezy for MSI GP60 2PE Leopard

Tags: linux, debian, driver

I use dual boot for **linux**/**windows**.
I'm trying to install wireless driver on **Debian_3.16-0.bpo.3-amd64** (*bpo* is for backport) Wheezy for my MSI laptop (MSI GP60 2PE Leopard).

I made **lspci -nn** to find reference about my network controller:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
```

So on the website of [linux Wireless](http://linux-wless.passys.nl/query_chipset.php?chipset=Intel)

My driver must be this one : ***iwlwifi***

I installed it,

```
apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

but it doesn't work...

During the boot, there are some errors :

```
Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux, in-tree:
[    4.847284] Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation
[    4.847449] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: irq 50 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.877181] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.923823] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode (-2)
[    4.923877] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    4.923878] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[    4.940971] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[    4.940987] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    4.940988] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.940996] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.940998] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.941006] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
```

If this can help you, I made ***modinfo iwlwifi*** and this is the output :

```
http://pastebin.com/s8ycnBwu
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix & Linux (unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that Aptitude package firmware-iwlwifi contains drivers for your device, lookup drivers from chip manufactor web sites...

I recommend to compare Kernel version and intel iwlwifi driver version, from: http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034398.htm

and how to guides can be found on: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi

With these links I hope you can find your own iwlwifi package, if it's supported.

You can check chipset via Windows Device Management...

Comment: Do you know if you can "export" driver on Linux?
For example : my driver worked on Xubuntu, if i can export it, that's will be great... but it seams impossible because driver is into the kernel